# Shortcut for adding performance counters to view in Perfmon?

Tags: performance-monitor

The green plus sign in PerfMon says ctrl + n should be the shortcut to access it, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it's `ctrl+shift+n` to add some counters. The Windows guys *almost* had it right in their own help text.